# Angular directive with a template, does not work with z-validate

Tags: angularjs, validation, templates, angularjs-directive, breeze

I am trying to create a **directive for a label:input** pair to use throughout my app. I also **rely on the z-validate attribute to use Breeze** to validate my input for me.

**The html file:**

```
<div data-af-label-input-pair data-af-model="vm.customer.firstName">
</div>
```

**The directive:**

app.directive('afLabelInputPair', function($compile) {

```
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        scope: {                    
            afModel: '='
        },
        templateUrl: '/app/templates/af-label-input-pair.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.opts = attrs;
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }
    }

    return directive;
});
```

**And the template file:**

```
<div>
<label>Some label:</label>
<input ng-model="afModel" data-z-validate />
</div>
```

This is displaying the html correctly on the page. But the z-validate does not kick in. In other words, **I would want the z-validate attribute to validate the vm.customer.firstName** for me.

If instead of using the directive & template, I just use the html directly, it works fine.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and I fixed it by moving the [span class="z-decorator"] added by the breeze data-z-validate directive after compilation to the parent element.

```
    // Angular directive [spaField] responsible for generating grid cell controls.
spa.app.directive('spaField', ['$compile', function ($compile)
{
    var directive = {
    restrict: 'A', /* Restrict this directive to attributes. */
    replace: true, /* The given element will be replaced in the link function. */
    link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
        // The data-z-validate directive will append a [<span class="z-decorator"] to the following [input] element, by using the jquery "append" function.
        var html = '<input type="text" data-ng-model="firstName" data-z-validate>'>;
        var compiled = $compile(html)($scope);

        // Get the [<span class="z-decorator"] appended to the input element by the z-validate directive.
        var span = compiled[0].parentNode.children[1];

        // The following 2 lines will only add the input element to the DOM and not the [<span class="z-decorator"], that is added by the z-validate directive.
        element.replaceWith(compiled);
        element = compiled;

        // Add the [<span class="z-decorator"] to the current parent element of the input element.
        element.parent().append(span);
    }
    };

    return directive;
}]);
```